# Gtk, modal dialog

Tags: c, gtk

I have one uncommon usage of gtk dialog. This dialog is in separate code file and have separate glade file for UI. This is because I want to have this dialog "replacable", for use in different projects. After job dialog is destroyed and every time again loaded wheen needed.
But here are problems with modality.

This is how I call dialog:

```
    int dlgresult;
    dlgresult = main_art(GTK_WIDGET(window), get_sif());
```

And this is interesting in dialog:

```
int main_art(GtkWidget *caller, int artSif)
{
GtkDialog *dlg_art;
char *xmlFile = "art.glade";
builder = gtk_builder_new ();
gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, xmlFile, NULL);
dlg_artikl = GTK_DIALOG(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "dlg_art"));
... other widgets...

gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(builder));

gtk_window_set_modal(GTK_WINDOW(GTK_DIALOG(dlg_art)), TRUE);
gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW(GTK_DIALOG(dlg_art)), GTK_WINDOW(GTK_WIDGET(caller)));

//placing dialog window relative to parent window
int x, y;
gdk_window_get_origin(GDK_WINDOW(GTK_WIDGET(caller)->window), &x, &y);
gtk_window_move(GTK_WINDOW(dlg_artikl), x+8, y);
//
int dlgresponse;
dlgresponse = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dlg_art));
if (dlgresponse == 1)
{
    //Save changes
}
gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(dlg_art));
return dlgresponse;
}
```

When dialog pops up I can still select anything on main window, even launch new dialog, few times. That means my dialog is not modal for my main appliacation.

Can this be done at shown way?
What is incorrect, my idea or my code?

Program compiles well and I have no errors on terminal when executing.

Answer (score 1):

In GTK2/gnome2 I use something like the following code to create a nonmodal dialog:

```
static void display_nonmodaldialog(GtkWidget *dialog, char *t)
{
  if(dialog!=NULL)
  {
    gtk_widget_hide(dialog);
    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
  }

  dialog=gtk_message_dialog_new(NULL, GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, GTK_MESSAGE_INFO, GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE, "%s", t);
  if(dialog)
  {
    g_signal_connect_swapped(dialog, "response", G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), dialog);
    gtk_widget_show_all(dialog);
  }
}
```

In order to display a modal dialog you'd replace the gtk_message_dialog_new line with something like:

```
dialog=gtk_message_dialog_new(NULL, GGTK_DIALOG_MODAL, GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, GTK_MESSAGE_INFO, GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE, "%s", t);
```

Also see: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkDialog.html#GtkDialogFlags

Flags used to influence dialog construction.

GTK_DIALOG_MODAL
    Make the constructed dialog modal, see gtk_window_set_modal().

GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT
    Destroy the dialog when its parent is destroyed, see gtk_window_set_destroy_with_parent().

Comment: I also uses such "classic" dialogs for messageboxex and so. But note, here is different situation. Whole dialog is in other file and it is not even referenced in main file. But should block main window. Both shares same "main_loop".

Answer (score 1):

After spending about 2 hours trying to make the same thing work I found some ground rules for modal windows in GTK+:

1. The "transient for" should be set BEFORE the modality.
2. Both should be set after the window has been shown.